# How to count the calls of a recursive function (Increment by 1) | C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code as below. It accepts an input and it prints line by line steps to solve the Hanoi problem. All I want to do is to print in each line step1,step2 and so on,from 1 until the end of the steps like the example below:

Enter the number of disks: 3

Step 1: 1-->2 Move one disk from the original peg to the extra peg
Step 2: 1-->3 Move one disk from the original peg to the destination peg
Step 3: 2-->3 Move one disk from the extra peg to the destination peg

```
  #include <iostream>
int count=1;
     void ToH(int dskToMv, int cLocation, string orpeg, int tmpLocation, string expeg, int fLocation, string depeg)
    {
         if( dskToMv != 0 ) 
        {
count++;
            ToH( dskToMv-1, cLocation, orpeg, fLocation, depeg, tmpLocation, expeg);
            cout<<"Step "<<count<<": Move one disk from the "<< orpeg << " to the " << depeg
                << " " << cLocation << " -> " << fLocation << endl;
            ToH( dskToMv-1, tmpLocation, expeg, cLocation, orpeg, fLocation, depeg);
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int c;
        cout << "Enter the number of disks: ";
        cin >> c;
        ToH(c, 1, "original peg ", 2, "extra peg", 3, "destination peg");
    }
```

Comment: Add another `int step` parameter to `ToH()` that increments in every call.

Comment: do I need a loop ?

Comment: May be a loop would be better than recursion, but you don't need one no.

Comment: I use as parameter int step=1 then I  add step++ at the end of the if statement but it prints 1. Increment doesn't work

Comment: Increment the parameter in the next call to `ToH()`.

Comment: it prints  3,3,5,3,5,5,7 I want to print 1,2,3,4,5...

Comment: Your code here is just plain incomplete. Keep trying. Note that recursive functions actually have to do something other than call themselves endlessly.

Answer (score 0):

In recursion, when you need to "keep" track of something per iteration, there are a few ways:

1. Primitive global variables - These only allow single states to be kept. If the recursion branches and such, it might not work because one branch will overwrite the value that another branch is using. For simply storing things like counts and such these tend to work well.
2. Pass parameters to the function - Parameters to a function are stored on the stack. When the function is called they are pushed, so for each recursion we end up with a "stack" of parameter values per iteration call. This works well with recursion because different branches do not destroy others values(popping occurs at the end of the function call and only pops the values that the call pushed).
3. Use complex global data structures. These essentially store the parameters outside the function call and allow more complex things to take place(e.g., use a queue instead of a stack) but require more work. Because they are external to the function they can be looked at by other branches if required.

All you need to do is declare a global int and then increment it in the function call. Every time the function is called the value is incremented and hence counts the number of function calls. Since it is only incremented we have no issues with branching(since every branch would do the same thing and hence be indistinguishable).

```
int count = 0;
 void ToH(int dskToMv, int cLocation, string orpeg, int tmpLocation, string expeg, int fLocation, string depeg)
{
   count++;
     if( dskToMv != 0 ) 
    {
        ToH( dskToMv-1, cLocation, orpeg, fLocation, depeg, tmpLocation, expeg);
        cout<<" Move one disk from the "<< orpeg << " to the " << depeg
            << " " << cLocation << " -> " << fLocation << " - " << count << endl;
        ToH( dskToMv-1, tmpLocation, expeg, cLocation, orpeg, fLocation, depeg);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to allow for backtracking and hence actually count the "levels", you can just use a parameter:

```
 void ToH(int dskToMv, int cLocation, string orpeg, int tmpLocation, string expeg, int fLocation, string depeg, int count = 0)
{
     if( dskToMv != 0 ) 
    {
        ToH( dskToMv-1, cLocation, orpeg, fLocation, depeg, tmpLocation, expeg, count + 1);
        cout<<" Move one disk from the "<< orpeg << " to the " << depeg
            << " " << cLocation << " -> " << fLocation << " - " << count << endl;
        ToH( dskToMv-1, tmpLocation, expeg, cLocation, orpeg, fLocation, depeg, count + 1);
    }
}
```

Not all methods are the same. When you learn to think of recursion as being a sort of "search" on a large branching data structure, it is easier to think about these things.  When you only use simple recursion that is equivalent to iteration, then there is not much distinction between these different methods.

Comment: it 's not incrementing by 1.

Comment: it works if I print the count before the if statement. If I print in inside the if statement I get wrong number counting

Comment: @Eternal It's not wrong, just out of order. Because you have two calls to ToH, you have a binary branching that takes place for every recursion. So you are printing in an pre-order type of traversal. That is, The first call is sort of like a Left and the second call is a right. Depending on when dskToMv == 0, we will end up with stuff like LLLRLLLRLLLRRLRLRLRLRLLLRR which seems like it might be out of order but it is because of how one is traversing the data structure. Basically it's not counting what you want/think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a static variable.
Increment this variable every time the function is (recursively)called.

```
#include <iostream>

 void ToH(int dskToMv, int cLocation, string orpeg, int tmpLocation, string expeg, int fLocation, string depeg)
{
    static int count=0 
    if( dskToMv != 0 ) 
    {
        count++;
        ToH( dskToMv-1, cLocation, orpeg, fLocation, depeg, tmpLocation, expeg);
        cout<<"Step "<<count<<": Move one disk from the "<< orpeg << " to the " << depeg
            << " " << cLocation << " -> " << fLocation << endl;
        ToH( dskToMv-1, tmpLocation, expeg, cLocation, orpeg, fLocation, depeg);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int c;
    cout << "Enter the number of disks: ";
    cin >> c;
    ToH(c, 1, "original peg ", 2, "extra peg", 3, "destination peg");
}
```

Hope this helps